# Label null exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am receiving a null exception every time I try to send the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` to the label.  Any ideas why?

This is what im using.

```
String Utilizador = Page.User.Identity.Name;

Response.Write(Utilizador);

Label1.Text = Utilizador;
```

Comment: Please add the stacktrace of the exception you get. Its possible that Label1, Page or Page.User is null

Comment: One of `User` or `Identity` is `null`. Is the server setup to demand authorization?

Comment: What does `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` return?

Comment: even if im logged it always te same, the reponse.writes gives the right value.

Comment: In that case, where is `Label1` initialized?

Comment: page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated gives true

Comment: everything is in master page for now

Comment: What happens if you set `Label1.Text` to a static value, such as "test"?  It seems as if `Label1` hadn't been initialized, you would get a compile time error.

Comment: Can you show us where you declare / initialize `Label1`?  Can you show us the server control that's in your .aspx page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are authenticated and you're getting the `NullReferenceException` in `Label1.Text = Utilizador;`, you don't have a reference to that label.

> everything is in master page for now

Rename it on the MasterPage, compile it, name it again `Label1`(i would strongly recommended to use better names for example `LblUserName`). Then recompile it.

Comment: i know that its for testing propose only

Comment: the label, it was the damn label. thanks, goingo to try now the other code to get the headloginname

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable non-authenticated users.  In web.config:

```
<authorization><deny users="?" /></authorization>
```

Comment: that happens even when i have a condition only to work when logged

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate your Label

```
  Label Label1 = new Label();
  Label1.Text = Utilizador;
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to add authentication tag in web.config as below.

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```